# Forced refresh of a binding Label (C# Windows Form)

Tags: c#, winforms

I would like to display the name of the object currently built in a label (Windows Form)

My label doesn't refresh in real-time. When I put a DialogBox or something else after each iteration, the label takes the good value and is well updated, but when I let my code run without "breaks", the label seems to bug and his value never changes...

I have the same kind of code for a progress bar and everything is working well.

ModelBuilder.cs

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private Substation currentSubstation;

public Substation CurrentSubstation
{
    get
    {
        return this.currentSubstation;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value != this.currentSubstation)
        {
            this.currentSubstation = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName = "")
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public void Build()
{
    foreach (string substationUri in substationsUri)
    {                 
        Substation substation = new Substation(new Uri(substationUri));
        this.CurrentSubstation = substation;
        /* code */
    } 
}
```

View.cs

```
private void StartImportation_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.model = new ModelBuilder(....);
   this.myLabel.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", this.model, "CurrentSubstation.name"));
   this.model.Build();
}
```

Comment: Do this before DataBindings.Add():    this.myLabel.DataBindings.Clear();

Comment: It doesn't work better, the progress bar is OK but the label stills freez